# Error after ORMReload() on CF10

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a weird error on my site. I'm using CF10 using the native ORM and FW/1. The back end is SQL server 2012. I have all my entities properly mapped and working fine. However, whenever I perform a change and execute the ORMReload() command, it throw's me an ORM error:

"An association from the table CategoryName refers to an unmapped class:"

If I go into CFAdmin and reload the template cache, the error goes away and everything works fine. If I remove the mapping from CategoryName, then the error message appears with another entity. I wonder if anyone had any problem like this.

Comment: Can you add your mappings to your question? It's tough to guess at what the problem is without seeing the code. You might also try cross posting this to the cf-orm-dev group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cf-orm-dev

Comment: Thanks Sean. It's a very difficult question, that's why I was asking if someone has ever faced that. I'll ask on cf-orm-dev, I think it will be easier to have it answered there.